# APNS open connection meaning

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

What does the APN (apple push notification), open connection mean.
Does it mean that the connection is open (a socket which has a IP and Port) and it never closes that socket?

Also apart from performance reasons, what is the need of keeping the connection open?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, opening a connection between your server and Apple's APN server means an open socket. Apple requests to keep the socket open as long as possible and use the same connection for sending multiple notifications.

This is important mostly when you are sending many notifications in a short time period, because if you open and close the connection many times in a short time period, Apple may treat it as a DDoS attack. If you are sending few notifications, and there is a long gap between them, you can close the connection and open a new one.

> ...developers are expected to open a connection and leave it open. If
>   a connection is opened and closed repeatedly, APNs will treat it as a
>   denial of service attack and block connections for a period of time.
>
> This temporary block will expire if no connection attempts are made
>   for about one hour.

([Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html))